# Laravel - production.ERROR: Property [is_approved] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

I am working on this code in a project built with Laravel-5.8

```
class HrEmployee extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'hr_employees';
   protected $primaryKey = 'id';

   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_code',
              'user_id',
              'hr_status',
              'address',
     ];

   public function appraisalgoals()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoal', 'id', 'employee_id'); 
   }
}


class AppraisalGoal extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'appraisal_goals';

   protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'employee_id',
              'employee_code',
              'is_published',
              'is_approved',
     ];

   public function employee()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','employee_id');
   }
}
```

Controller

```
public function employee_goals()
{
  $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

$published_goals = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->get(); 

    return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals')
            ->with('published_goals', $published_goals);       
}
```

view

```
   @foreach($published_goals as $key => $published_goal)
                        <td>
                            {{isset($published_goal->employee_code) ? $published_goal->employee_code : 'None'}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if ($published_goal->appraisalgoals->is_approved == 3)
                                <span class="badge bg-success" >Approved</span>
                            @elseif ($published_goal->appraisalgoals->is_approved == 2)
                                <span class="badge bg-danger">Not Approved</span>
                            @elseif ($published_goal->appraisalgoals->is_approved == 1)
                                <span class="badge bg-info">Awaiting Approval</span>                                  
                            @else
                                <span class="badge bg-black">Draft</span>                                    
                            @endif                                   
                        </td>  
   @endforeach
```

employee_id is in it as a relationship foreign key

protected $table = 'appraisal_goals';

protected $fillable = [
'id',
'employee_id',
'employee_code',
'is_published',
'is_approved',
];

When I rendered  the view, I got this error:

> production.ERROR: Property [is_approved] does not exist on this collection instance

is_approved is in appraisal_goals (AppraisalGoal) model

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your foreign key reference is wrong in `appraisalgoals()` relationship definition. change it to

```
public function appraisalgoals()
   {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appraisal\AppraisalGoal', 'employee_id', 'id'); 
   }
```

now as you defined your relationship as hasMany, that means you may have multiple data for a employee. so when you are accessing relationship, it returns a collection instead of an object. your data belongs to an object not to a collection. when you are accessing `$published_goal->appraisalgoals->is_approved` you are actually trying to get value from a collection `appraisalgoals`. you need to loop through the collection to get an object and then you can access value from that object.

```
@foreach ($published_goal->appraisalgoals as $key => $value)
    {{ $value->is_approved }}
@endforeach
```

now you can access the first instance like

`$published_goal->appraisalgoals()->first()->is_approved`

if you define hasOne relationship then you can access value directly as you are accessing now
`$published_goal->appraisalgoals->is_approved`

hope you understands the issue. for your reference [heres](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) the relationship doc from laravel.

Answer (score 0):

With get() method you get a collection (all data that match the query), try to use first() instead, it return only one element, like this:

```
$published_goals = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->first();
```

Let me know what happens

Answer (score 0):

$published_goal->appraisalgoals  would be a collection [] because you are using HasMany, you would need another loop.

```
@foreach($published_goals as $key => $published_goal)
    <td>
        {{isset($published_goal->employee_code) ? $published_goal->employee_code : 'None'}}
    </td>
<td>
    @foreach($published_goal->appraisalgoals as $appraisalgoal)
        @if ($appraisalgoal->is_approved == 3)
            <span class="badge bg-success" >Approved</span>
        @elseif ($appraisalgoal->is_approved == 2)
            <span class="badge bg-danger">Not Approved</span>
        @elseif ($appraisalgoal->is_approved == 1)
            <span class="badge bg-info">Awaiting Approval</span>                                  
        @else
            <span class="badge bg-black">Draft</span>                                    
        @endif      
    @endforeach          
</td> 
@endforeach
```

You could also change your relationship to a HasOne. Does a published_goal have many appraisalgoal or just one?

You could also target ->first();  The first appraisalgoals associated with the $published_goal.

Don't forget to lazy/eager load if you end up doing the second loop to avoid multiple calls for the same data.

```
$published_goals = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->with('author')->get();
```

//Or

```
$published_goals = HrEmployee::where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('hr_status', 0)->get(); 
$published_goals->load('appraisalgoals');
```